# Passing list of integers from AJAX call to C# method returns null

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to pass an array of integers from my client-side javascript to server-side C# using ajax. However it always comes up as null in code-behind. I can't seem to find the issue here. I had a similar ajax method but with an array of strings and it works, but it doesn't with integers?

My ajax method:

```
var theList = [1,2,3,4,5];
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'MyPage?handler=SaveList',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    headers: {
        RequestVerificationToken:
           $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({ theList: theList }),
    success: function(data){
    alert("Success");
    }
});
```

My code-behind:

```
public JsonResult OnPostSaveList([FromBody]int[] theList) //<<<Returns 'null'
{
    foreach(int data in theList){
    //save to datebase
    }
    return new JsonResult("Done");
}
```

The issue here is I get a null value from `theList` in the code-behind.
Checking the JSON.stringify, it seems to be passing `"[1,2,3,4,5]"`. Not sure if there is a type mis-match here.

Comment: Please show us the exact payload being passed, from Chrome developer tools -> Network tab.

Comment: {"dateList":[1609430400000,1609516800000]}

Comment: That doesn't look like `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: It also has a different name `dateList` vs `theList` - C# will match on *names* so they need to match.

Comment: You're right it's not. 
If I use `JSON.stringify({ theList: theList})` then payload becomes `{"theList":[1609430400000,1609516800000,1609603200000]}`
If I use  `JSON.stringify(theList)` then it becomes just `[1609430400000,1609516800000,1609603200000]`.

Comment: I don't believe you. The name is different (`dateList` vs `theList`). There is no way that 1 became 1609430400000. I think it is likely you aren't showing us the actual code.

Comment: Does the length of the integer affect the ajax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Max value of int32 is `2147483647`, while `1609430400000` is out of range, so you receive the null value.

Instead of `int[]`, you can use `long[]` to receive the value.

```
var theList = [1609430400000, 1609516800000, 1609603200000];
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Index?handler=SaveList',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    headers: {
        RequestVerificationToken:
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(theList),
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success");
    }
});
```

Handler:

```
    public JsonResult OnPostSaveList([FromBody] long[] theList) //<<<Returns 'null'
    {
        foreach (var data in theList)
        {
            //save to datebase
        }
        return new JsonResult("Done");
    }
```

Request Payload:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @mj1313, Thanks for your detailed answer. I figured that was the case shortly after posting my previous answer. Thanks for you help! Sorry it took me so long to reply. Cheers!